# Get Sum of Data from Second Dataset in the Second Tablix of SSRS report with Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have two different dataset which has a common value placed in two different Tablix in Report Builder tool.  I want to achieve a SUM of `ELEC_DATA` in the second Tablix.

I have already tried using this expression.

```
=LOOKUP(Field!COMP_ID.value,Field!COMP_ID.value,Field!ELEC_DATA.value,"DATASET2")
```

The result shows nothing at all -- no errors as well.

Then I tried with custom code.

```
=code.sumlookup(LOOKUPSET(Field!COMP_ID.value,Field!COMP_ID.value,Field!ELEC_DATA.value,"DATASET2"))
```

The Result I am getting is "0".

The expected result would be the addition of `ELEC_DATA` like shown in the pic attached
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're using the `LOOKUP` function incorrectly.  The `LOOKUP` function only requires 4 parameters to be used.

```
=LOOKUP([SourceValue], [DestinationValue], [LookedUpValue], "[SourceDataset]")
```

However, I'm not sure this is the best or even a viable solution to your issue.  Honestly, this would be much easier if you were able to combine these two datasets into a single dataset query.

```
SELECT PAC2_ID, A.COMP_ID, DATE, ELEC_DATA 
FROM TABLE1 A JOIN TABLE2 B ON B.COMP_ID = A.COMP_ID
```

From there, you can use a Grouping on the second Tablix based on `PAC2_ID` which removes the need for any expressions.  It should sum the values automatically when you apply the grouping.

Comment: i cannot join these two tables they are from different database if combined will give cartesian product and other things involved i want to do this in two tablix, not talking about two different table. Tablix refer to two different set of tables used in the report builder. Updated the code i used sorry that was incorrect a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Alright Let's try something like this.

In your 2nd Tablix create one more Column let's call it "PAC2ID_Calculated".
Now for this Column we will use lookup Expression `=Lookup(Field!COMP_ID.value, 
          Field!COMP_ID.value, 
            Field!PAC2_ID, 
                       "FirstDataset")`

Now what will this return in your new Column, It will return PAC2_ID for COMP_ID from first dataset and your 2nd Tablix will be something like below

[image]

Once you get this, Group it based on PAC2_ID, you will get expected Result.

[image]

You can Hide COMP_ID column.

Comment: A few notes to improve your answer, the expression needs to be `=Lookup(Fields!COMP_ID.Value,  Fields!COMP_ID.Value,  Fields!PAC2_ID.Value,  "DataSet1")`.  SSRS is case sensitive. Grouping needs to be by the same expression.  Also, you'll need to use `=SUM(Fields!ELEC_DATA.Value)` in the `ELEC DATA` column to get those values.